# Problem with mesomeric effect in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I'm trying to draw mesomeric effect for a molecule using `chemfig` I would like to create something like this:

[image]

From the [documentation page](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig_doc_en.pdf#page=19) (see chapter 11 "Representing electron movements")seems easy but I've spent the last 4 hours without any success. The first arrow is the most difficult because goes form lewis pair to the bond.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlewis{4pt}{0.8em}{black}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6((-H_{2}@{sb1}\lewis{26,N}{\hspace{7mm}\scriptstyle})@{dncc}=-=(-N=N-*6(=-=(-OH)-=-))-=-=)}
\chemmove{
\draw[->](sb1)..controls +(90:4mm) and +(45:4mm)..(dncc);}
\end{document}
```

This is the molecule without anything else:

```
\chemfig{*6((-H_{2}\lewis{26,N}{\hspace{7mm}\scriptstyle})=-=(-N=N-*6(=-=(-OH)-=-))-=-=)}
```

If possible I would like an explanation of my faults!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how to draw the 2 first arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6((-[@{a1}]H_2@{a2}\Lewis{26,N})=[@{r1}]-[@{r2}]=(-N=N-*6(=-=(-OH)-=-))-=-=)}
\chemmove[-stealth,shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]{%
    \draw(a2)..controls +(90:5mm) and +(135:5mm)..(a1);% first arrow
    \draw(r1)..controls +(225:12mm) and +(300:12mm)..(r2);% ring arrow
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 thanks, so when I have to use @{a2} instead of [@{a2}]?

Comment: `@{<name>}` to put a node in an atom and `[@{<name>}]` to put it in a bond.