# How to embed TeXlive 2018 chemfig diagram with mesomeric effects inside of standalone environment?

Tags: standalone, chemfig, texlive-2018

I am trying to programmatically draw individual chemfig diagrams based on "live" input data and embed them into an interactive dashboard. As such, I am not looking to generate a scientific article.  So, I am using `\documentclass{standalone}`. Unfortunately, this appears to break the drawing of mesomeric arrows in `chemfig 1.33`. This can be confirmed by comparing the snippet in the answer to [Problem with mesomeric effect in chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168022/problem-with-mesomeric-effect-in-chemfig) with standalone and article document classes. With standalone the arrows are either not drawn or drawn in completely the wrong spots. See the figure below.

[image: what chemfig produces in standalone]

Is there an alternative way to generating single figures which works with mesomeric effects by tricking the article class to behave like standalone?

P.S. Here is the exact code being run:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{ddbond}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=4pt]
  {
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{0pt}}
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{2pt}{2pt}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{2pt}}
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{0pt}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}
\tikzset{lddbond/.style={decorate,decoration=ddbond}}
\tikzset{rddbond/.style={decorate,decoration={ddbond,mirror}}}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6((-[@{a1}]H_2@{a2}\Lewis{26,N})=[@{r1}]-[@{r2}]=(-N=N-*6(=-=(-OH)-=-))-=-=)}
\chemmove[-stealth,shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]{%
\draw(a2)..controls +(90:5mm) and +(135:5mm)..(a1);% first arrow
\draw(r1)..controls +(225:12mm) and +(300:12mm)..(r2);% ring arrow
}
\end{document}
```

Update:

After wandering around the configuration space for a while, I discovered that using `documentclass{article}` doesn't fix this - I could have sworn it was working before. Even with article the output looks the same:

[image: After switching to documentclass article]

This time the code I used was:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{ddbond}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=4pt]
  {
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{0pt}}
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{2pt}{2pt}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{2pt}}
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{0pt}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}
\tikzset{lddbond/.style={decorate,decoration=ddbond}}
\tikzset{rddbond/.style={decorate,decoration={ddbond,mirror}}}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6((-[@{a1}]H_2@{a2}\Lewis{26,N})=[@{r1}]-[@{r2}]=(-N=N-*6(=-=(-OH)-=-))-=-=)}
\chemmove[-stealth,shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]{%
\draw(a2)..controls +(90:5mm) and +(135:5mm)..(a1);% first arrow
\draw(r1)..controls +(225:12mm) and +(300:12mm)..(r2);% ring arrow
}
\end{document}
```

Adding `\pagestyle{empty}` following the advice from the comments to the above template does result in a working figure inside of the article class.

[image: with pagestyle empty]

Comment: I discovered this has to do with the way I'm building the image file. I was using `latex` followed by `dvipdf`. If instead I use `pdflatex`, then the arrows get placed in the right spot, although there is clipping.

Comment: A better question could be: why are you still using texlive 2018? Both tikz and chemfig are actively maintaned

Comment: I think I am using the TeXlive 2018 distribution (revision 49885). I might also be using TeXlive 2013. It's a bit confusing to me which is actually being called. It's whatever the default is on CentOS 7 (which for the sake of reproducibility and stability is what I'm stuck with).

Comment: Hold on a minute relative to my first comment. I'm still seeing the same problem from my autogenerated code. I may have "jumped the gun".

Comment: As you've now noticed the latex provided by Linux dists generally aren't kept up to date and it might be better to manually install the upstream texlive instead

Comment: Unfortunately, I am at the mercy of my system administrators - especially since the goal of my program is to work across multiple users and multiple computers on the internal network system.

Comment: I was hoping I had made a breakthrough after reading: https://anki.tenderapp.com/discussions/ankidesktop/9164-latex-chemfig-commands-dont-display-correctly. Now I'm not so sure.

Comment: Your code shows me two arrows when compiled in TeXLive 2020 (I had to change the `border` to `10pt` as it was cutting the arrow. It is not shown correctly in my copy of TeXLive 2019. But that is only an issue with `standalone` switching to `article` and it works just fine. Everything compiled using `pdflatex`

Comment: If you are just making images to use elsewhere, you can always use `article` and `\pagestyle{empty}` in the preable. That gives you an image with too much borders (which is why we like to use `standalone`) which can be externally trimmed using `pdfcrop`

Comment: So my guess is that this is some strange interaction between `chemfig` and `standalone` that have recently been fixed. Getting admins to care will be hard. I used to manage a number of servers and used the upstream TeXLive, not the ones from RedHat, but that was only because I'm a dedicated LaTeX user. Other admins just did not care.

Comment: I'm pretty confident I was able to get it to render correctly at least once - to the extent that the only problem was that the `standalone` documentation class was merely clipping the arrows, rather than placing them in the wrong spots. However, I didn't save whatever configuration enabled that.

Comment: I think the reason that I had seen it occasionally working is that it requires running pdflatex multiple times. I didn't realize that was a requirement.

Comment: I always use the latexmk tool, so it does it for me